# AngularJS. How to disable auto-scroll to top of my page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tell me please, how can I disable auto-upto top of my page?
If I use hash nav:

```
<a href="#/index">Goto index</a>
```

my page doest up to top, but if I use AngularJS:
Html:

```
<a ng-href="#/index">Goto index</a>
```

JS:

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/index', {
          template:'...',
          controller: 'RouteCtrl'
      })
```

my page scrolled to top. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 23):

I find it a bit strange that your plain `href` doesn't scroll and `ng-href` scrolls, I thought it was the other way round...

But, to the solution; It's up to the browser to scroll on hash changes, so usually to disable it you need to intercept and `preventDefault()` the event and then change the location by yourself. When using Angular, you can either define some attribute directive for the `<a>` element or just define your own `a` directive.

If you use `ng-view`, it relies on `$anchorScroll` service with view updates to simulate the behaviour what the browser would normally do, as Angular already intercepts the event. You can prevent the scroll on view load by providing your own `$anchorScroll` which does nothing:

```
angular.module('yourModule', []).value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop);
```

Comment: the code supplied does the job.  FYI using href or ng-href doesn't seem to make any difference.  I use href as my links are properly set from the start.

Comment: @Jawa I am running into similar issue, added the code you suggested with no success. Here is the question with code examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283979/how-to-disable-anchorscroll-in-angularjs-ng-view

Comment: This nukes autoscroll on the whole site, not just the one page.

Comment: I dont like this solution either. Overriding a whole service is a bad idea :/

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll), the proper way to do this is:

```
angular.module('yourModule',[]).config( ['$anchorScrollProvider', 
    function($anchorScrollProvider) {
        $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();
    }]
);
```

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't disable all scrolling.  It simply turns off `$scrollAnchor`'s watch on `$location.hash()`.  As such, I don't think it applies to this particular case (changing views).  If the the issue was not wanting it to scroll when you set `$location.hash()` then this is the fix.

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
assessmentApp.run(['$anchorScroll', function($anchorScroll) {
    $anchorScroll = angular.noop;
}])
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer solves the specific question above, but it does prevent Angular from scrolling to the top of the page when an `$http` request completes.