# How to disable $anchorScroll in angularjs ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive for bootstrap tabs to show the tab and switch the route based on the url passed in as a parameter of change-selection.

Every time tab is clicked view loads and entire page scrolls to the top. I am trying to disable page scrolling but no matter what I try I can't get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

JS Code:

```
var reportApp = angular.module('reportApp', [])
//Disable anchorScroll
.value('$anchorScroll', angular.noop)
.config(
  ['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "t1.html",
        controller: 'T1Ctrl'}
      )
      ...
 }

//Directive to switch tab
reportApp.directive('changeSelection', function ($location) {
        return function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(element).tab('show');
                $location.path(attr.changeSelection);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabContainer" class="span12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="reportTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" change-selection="/tendencies">Tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding style to the tab content div. This prevents resizing of the div and browser refresh. So after all it had nothing to do with angularjs.

Changed from:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="tab-content" style="min-height: 500px">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the /tendencies path mapped to a template?  if not, then ng-view will remove the content of the t1.html when you click on the tab, this forces the browser to reduce the page height and might lead you to think that it is scrolling to the top.

For a quick test add the /tendencies path to the route provider and see if the scrolling doesn't happen.

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "t1.html",
    controller: 'T1Ctrl'}
  ).when("/tendencies", {
    templateUrl: "t1.html"});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes I do, I extracted and modified the code that's why the example does not have it.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem with a much simpler setup (the bare minimum, without using bootstrap.js)?  I am assuming that this problem is not a browser specific.

Comment: I added github repo https://github.com/anazimok/angular-test-app. I will try to reproduce it there.